# Embedded GUI - Similar to GWEN?

Tags: user-interface, embedded, stm32

I wrote a library to use different LCDs, such as TFT LCDs with TouchScreens with an existing RTOS.
The library does include all highlevel routines like drawing lines, circles, render fonts and so on.

Now, I would like to make the library more useful and give it a small GUI toolkit so the user can create buttons, sliders, radio buttons and all the other classical GUI elements.
There is [GWEN](http://code.google.com/p/gwen/) which works pretty well.

My question: Are there free, opensource libraries like GWEN out there which are easy to use for my purpose?
I cannot take stuff like Qt because I'd need to implement the entire internals like event handling and stuff. Also, the RTOS would need to support POSIX. I really just want the GUI elements, nothing more. It must be very lightweight and only implement all the highlevel classes. It should be as lightweight as possible, because it's supposed to run on small microcontrollers like the STM32F1 (ARM Cortex-M3 with less than 100kB of RAM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, at the end I decided to write my own: http://ugfx.io

Answer (score 1):

[Gwork](https://github.com/billyquith/GWork) is a fork of GWEN. You might try that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to Gwork. I am now pretty happy with µGFX. It covers all my needs and is super fast, slim & portable. No 3rd party dependencies at all. Not even libc.